# Semantic error in giving a flag to the point with the minimum distance in Qt

Tags: c++, qt

I'm working on a qt project. I'm computing the distances between each point entered by the user on mouse click and some virtual points I declared. The point will take the flag of the the virtual point with the minimum distance.I have a semantic error in my project. I tried to trace the code but I didn't understand why is that happening.
The problem is that I'm always getting the flag 1.when I enter 2 points I got the flag 11. it is always 1.

When I debug for 2 points:

```
138 ,  134 
distance 1  0 
distance 2 7 
distance 3  14 
distance 4 5 
distance 5  8.60233 
distance 6  14.8661 
flag  " 1" 
183 ,  168 
distance 1  56.4004 
distance 2 52.4786 
distance 3  49.2443 
distance 4 52.4976 
distance 5  48.2597 
distance 6  44.7214 
flag  " 11"
```

I think the problem is here:

```
      if (min_distance== distance_pt_1 ){
      char_flag=char_flag.append("1");
      }
      else  if (min_distance== distance_pt_2 ){
  char_flag=char_flag.append("2");
 }
      else  if (min_distance== distance_pt_3 ){
  char_flag=char_flag.append("3");
 }
      else  if (min_distance== distance_pt_4 ){
  char_flag=char_flag.append("4");
 }
      else  if (min_distance== distance_pt_5 ){
  char_flag=char_flag.append("5");
 }
      else  if (min_distance== distance_pt_6 ){
  char_flag=char_flag.append("6");
 }

      qDebug()<<"flag " <<char_flag;
```

The code from beginning :

```
 foreach( QGraphicsItem * item, list )
     {
             min_distance=scene->width();
             distance_pt_1=scene->width();
             distance_pt_2=scene->width();
             distance_pt_3=scene->width();
             distance_pt_4=scene->width();
             distance_pt_5=scene->width();
             distance_pt_6=scene->width();

              int xx=item->x();
              int yy=item->y();
              qDebug()<<xx<<", "<< yy;

        distance_pt_1=qSqrt(qPow(xx- pt_1.x(),2)+qPow(yy- pt_1.y(),2));
        distance_pt_2=qSqrt(qPow(xx- pt_2.x(),2)+qPow(yy- pt_2.y(),2));
        distance_pt_3=qSqrt(qPow(xx- pt_3.x(),2)+qPow(yy- pt_3.y(),2));
        distance_pt_4=qSqrt(qPow(xx- pt_4.x(),2)+qPow(yy- pt_4.y(),2));
        distance_pt_5=qSqrt(qPow(xx- pt_5.x(),2)+qPow(yy- pt_5.y(),2));
        distance_pt_6=qSqrt(qPow(xx- pt_6.x(),2)+qPow(yy- pt_6.y(),2));

              if (distance_pt_1 < min_distance)
         {
             min_distance= distance_pt_1;

         }
              else  if (distance_pt_2 < min_distance)
         {
             min_distance= distance_pt_2;

         }
              else  if (distance_pt_3 < min_distance)
         {
             min_distance= distance_pt_3;

         }
              else  if (distance_pt_4 < min_distance)
         {
             min_distance= distance_pt_4;

         }
              else  if (distance_pt_5 < min_distance)
         {
             min_distance= distance_pt_5;

         }
              else  if (distance_pt_6 < min_distance)
         {
             min_distance= distance_pt_6;

         }



      if (min_distance== distance_pt_1 ){
  char_flag=char_flag.append("1");
 }
      else  if (min_distance== distance_pt_2 ){
  char_flag=char_flag.append("2");
 }
      else  if (min_distance== distance_pt_3 ){
  char_flag=char_flag.append("3");
 }
      else  if (min_distance== distance_pt_4 ){
  char_flag=char_flag.append("4");
 }
      else  if (min_distance== distance_pt_5 ){
  char_flag=char_flag.append("5");
 }
      else  if (min_distance== distance_pt_6 ){
  char_flag=char_flag.append("6");
 }

      qDebug()<<"flag " <<char_flag;

  } // foreach loop
```

Comment: What's the error? What did you expect and what do you get?

Comment: sorry I've edited the post

Comment: Incidentally, repeated code like that should ring a bell that you should be using an array...

Comment: The problem is that I'm always getting the flag 1.when I enter 2 points I got the flag 11. it is always 1

Comment: What datatype do `min_distance`, `distance_pt_i` have?

Comment: the datatype is integer.

Comment: Try double or qreal. `qSqrt` returns a qreal and you're loosing accuracy with integers whether this is the root of your problem or not

Comment: Can you qDebug the 6 distances and show them to us?

Comment: by the way (and still I do not think this is the main problem) `char_flag=char_flag.append("x");` should be `char_flag.append("x");`

Comment: I edited the code, I added the debug that I have for 2 points. The second point must have 6 flag but the flag is 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not all of your conditions are checked because you are using `if` - `else if`. That means the first condition is always true (`distance_pt_1` is smaller than the initial `min_distance`) but the next ones are never evaluated. Simply remove the `else` clauses.

```
if (distance_pt_1 < min_distance) {
    min_distance = distance_pt_1;
}
if (distance_pt_2 < min_distance) {
    min_distance = distance_pt_2;
}
if (distance_pt_3 < min_distance) {
    min_distance = distance_pt_3;
}
if (distance_pt_4 < min_distance) {
    min_distance = distance_pt_4;
}
if (distance_pt_5 < min_distance) {
    min_distance = distance_pt_5;
}
if (distance_pt_6 < min_distance) {
    min_distance = distance_pt_6;
}
```